# File Name in the WHERE clause of Mysql returns nothing

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the this SELECT query that returns nothing from the specified table yet the path to the file is stored in that table;

SELECT * from tableName WHERE imageFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Albert Bayita\Desktop\MovieImages\TheLordOfTheRingsTheFellowship.jpg";

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The backslash character is the escape character in strings in MySQL. To put a backslash in a string literal in a query you have to escape it using double backslashes. Also a string in SQL uses apostrophes as delimiter, not quotation marks.

```
SELECT * from tableName WHERE imageFile = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Albert Bayita\\Desktop\\MovieImages\\TheLordOfTheRingsTheFellowship.jpg';
```

The best option is of course to use a parameterised query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your table `tableName` probably has no `imageFile` row with theat exact path.

Parhaps the path is stored differently (perhaps the \ is quoted to \)?

How do you know that is does exist exactly as you have entered in the query?

Comment: Well I know it exists in my database because I have been using it to load thumbnail images on a listview. I have been advised to use double slashes and I got what i expected. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 0):

why you store the whole path in the database

you should figure out something to store just the image name

or if you want to keep on storing the whole path

try

to double the backslash \

```
SELECT * from tableName WHERE imageFile = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Albert Bayita\\Desktop\\MovieImages\\TheLordOfTheRingsTheFellowship.jpg";
```