# MySql interpreter refuse filtering char/varchar contains BackSlash(es)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have saved FilePath in DbTable in form `\\IpAdress\Hdd\Folder\fileName.extension` and looks like as I unable search in DbTable by using Where clause f.e.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE myColumn = '\\IpAdress\Hdd\Folder\fileName.extension'
```

sure is possible by using very lazy select clause LIKE, is there another way or would be better to replace BackSlash with another char ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = '\\\\IpAdress\\Hdd\\Folder\\fileName.extension'
```

See this post

[File Name in the WHERE clause of Mysql returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055468/file-name-in-the-where-clause-of-mysql-returns-nothing)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your backslashes.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = '\\\\IpAdress\\Hdd\\Folder\\fileName.extension'
```